# Equation for standard error of linear predictor and 95% prediction intervals from logistic regression

Tags: r, machine-learning, prediction

I would like to present 95% prediction intervals in an online risk calculator.

1) After fitting a logistic model with `lrm` (which includes some restricted cubic splines), I export the equation using `latex()` and program the model as a risk calculator.

2) The trouble is that I want to also find the equations for the upper and lower limits of the 95% prediction intervals around the predicted probabilities to help users see the uncertainty in the predictions.

3) I know how to produce prediction intervals using the `predict(model,data,type="lp",se.fit)` method, but it is not the actual values I am interested in. Rather I need to get the equation.

The scenario is a common one in risk modelling but risk calculators very rarely show upper and lower prediction intervals.

**The first issue: how to calculate standard errors of the linear predictor**

From Sofroniou N, Hutcheson GD. Confidence intervals for the predictions of logistic regression in the presence and absence of a variance-covariance matrix. Understanding Statistics: Statistical Issues in Psychology, Education, and the Social Sciences. 2002 Feb 2;1(1):3-18.

[image: Asymptotic standard error of logit]

Not sure how I can create a single equation in the form logit(p) = B1X1+1.96*ASE_of_B1 + B2X2+1.96*ASE_of_B2... that I can then work with in excel or javascript etc to give people upper and lower 95% prediction limits.

Initially I thought I could just do something like:

```
#the main lrm object
fit<-lrm(y~rcs(x1,3)+x2+x3,data=data,X=T,Y=T)

#just creating some lrm objects to update later for user with latex()
fit.ucl<-fit
fit.lcl<-fit

#update the coefficients in the lrm objects to represent the upper and        
#lower bounds of the confidence intervals
fit.ucl$coefficients<-(fit$coefficients + 1.96*(sqrt(diag(vcov(fit)))))
fit.lcl$coefficients<-(fit$coefficients - 1.96*(sqrt(diag(vcov(fit)))))

#output the equations for each in latex
latex(fit)
latex(fit.ucl)
latex(fit.lcl)
```

but this is using only the diagonal of the vcov matrix and doesn’t take into account the off-diagonals (the covariances) as the above equation requires.

My model also includes restricted cubic spline-transformed variables, the interpretation of which is greatly facilitated by latex(model) or function(model). I could write an equation to compute SE of the LP in real time using the full varcov matrix if I could easily convert the b coefficients on the splinevar, splinevar` notation into b* splinevar + b* pmax(splinevar-knot1,0)^3 - b* pmax(splinevar-knot2,0)^3 + b* pmax(splinevar-knot3,0)^3.

Comment: Might be useful if you put an example of what you want?